# How do I take "Undefined" label that appears in the following report?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

The following report is of Asset Analysis in Odoo. When expanding the Asset categories respective assets are displayed but along with it undefined label also occurs like a iterative cycle in the report.The images attached is the screen shot of the scenario[image: Asset Analysis]

Comment: Did you check if an undefinded asset exists in your assets?